# Authentication issues with Nagios Mobile

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, authentication, nagios

I am working on a personal project on my home server and trying to get Nagios Mobile working. I've installed Nagios Core properly and can get to it by going to https://localhost/nagios3. However, when try to access https://localhost/nagiosmobile - I get the following error:

```
Access Denied: No authentication detected.
```

I've verified the Nagios Apache config file (nagiosmobile_apache.conf) to confirm that it has the proper rules configured and at this point, I'm not sure what else to think of. Also, I have restarted both the nagios and apache services.

Here is the nagiosmobile_apache.conf file (see the bottom section specifically to confirm proper auth configuration):

```
#modify this file to fit your apache configuration

Alias /nagiosmobile "/usr/local/nagiosmobile"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagiosmobile">
#  SSLRequireSSL
Options None
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

#  Allow from 127.0.0.1

######use the below lines for Nagios XI
# AuthName "Nagios Monitor XI"
#  AuthType Basic
# AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagiosxi/etc/htpasswd.users


######Use the below lines for a SOURCE install of Nagios Core
AuthName "Nagios Access"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users
require valid-user

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

For nagios web panel, we need user and password for that. To create `username nagiosadmin` [ change according to yours ] and after that it will prompt for `password`. Check below command.

```
# htpasswd -c /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

And last thing, you set wrong format in nagios configuration file in apache.

In last part,

it is Require not require. use capital R.

```
AuthName "Nagios Access"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Hi, I added a new user called nagiosmobile and made the change to the config file (capitalized the "r" in Require), however that did not fix the issue. I also restarted Apache. I thought with Nagios, if I have Core installed shouldn't Nagiosmobile use the same username and password to login?

Also, since Nagios Core is setup and installed properly the account has already been created with nagiosadmin. I did create a new account though called nagiosmobile for the new installation, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Had to look in this thread: https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=47937. Needed to move the nagiosmobile.conf file to the Apache /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ folder.